# React Native: How to create a list with items that overflow into the next column

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a React Native application (for tablets/ipad) that needs to display a list of items like the one shown [here](https://cdn-web.gofrugal.com/images/Kds/servquick-screen-big.webp).

The requirement is that the list should not be scrollable, and if an item's height is more than the remaining space in that column, it should be displayed on the next column.

I've tried using the `MasonryList` package (`@react-native-seoul/masonry-list`), but it doesn't seem to meet my requirements. Is there another package that I can use, or do I need to create my own custom solution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is that a ChatGPT log?